# XPCService not getting launched from app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode6, nsxpcconnection

I am trying a simple sample app on `XPCServices`, in which I am following below steps:

**Step 1:** Created a sample project and added target - `XPCServices` with name - `HelperProcess` to it. When the target is created XCode automatically generates below files:

1. HelperProcessProtocol.h
2. HelperProcess.h
3. HelperProcess.m
4. main.m

**Step 2:** In `main.m` added a log statement within implementation of `ServiceDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)listener:(NSXPCListener *)listener shouldAcceptNewConnection:(NSXPCConnection *)newConnection {
    // This method is where the NSXPCListener configures, accepts, and resumes a new incoming NSXPCConnection.
    NSLog(@"Log which is never displayed :(");
    // Configure the connection.
    // First, set the interface that the exported object implements.
    newConnection.exportedInterface = [NSXPCInterface interfaceWithProtocol:@protocol(HelperProcessProtocol)];

    // Next, set the object that the connection exports. All messages sent on the connection to this service will be sent to the exported object to handle. The connection retains the exported object.
    HelperProcess *exportedObject = [HelperProcess new];
    newConnection.exportedObject = exportedObject;

    // Resuming the connection allows the system to deliver more incoming messages.
    [newConnection resume];

    // Returning YES from this method tells the system that you have accepted this connection. If you want to reject the connection for some reason, call -invalidate on the connection and return NO.
    return YES;
}
```

**Step 3:** In `AppDelegate` added below code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    _connectionToService = [[NSXPCConnection alloc] initWithServiceName:@"HelperProcess"];
    _connectionToService.remoteObjectInterface = [NSXPCInterface interfaceWithProtocol:@protocol(HelperProcessProtocol)];
    [_connectionToService resume];
}
```

**Problem is -**

> When I launch the app, neither the log added in
>   listener:shouldAcceptNewConnection: is displayed nor the helper
>   process appears in Activity Monitor :(

Here is the code: [XPCShootOut](https://github.com/Daemon-Devarshi/XPCShootOut)

***Note:*** I am trying this on XCode 6.0

Is there any additional setup which I need to do to make it working? Please suggest.

**-- Update --**

I tried to refer this sample from apple: [AppSandboxLoginItemXPCDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AppSandboxLoginItemXPCDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012292-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

When I tried to run it on XCode 6, it displayed error message - 'No signing identity found'. Since I don't have registered mac developer account, in build settings for - iDecide and iDecideHelper I changed 'Code Signing Identity' as 'Don't Code Sign'.

I got a warning for each of the targets:

```
Code Sign warning: CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS specified without specifying CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY. It is not possible to add entitlements to a binary without signing it.
```

This time when I compiled the build, it worked as expected.

Now I tried to follow the steps specified in its ReadMe.txt file, specifically I performed these steps in my sample app:

**Step 1:** Updated - Main App Target -> Capabilities Tab

1. Turned on 'App Sandbox'
2. Turned on 'App Groups'
3. Added an app group - 'XYZ'

**Step 2:** Updated - Helper Target -> Capabilities Tab

1. Turned on 'App Sandbox'
2. Enabled 'Outgoing Connections (Client)'
3. Turned on 'App Groups'
4. Added an app group - 'XYZ'

**Step 3:** Updated - Helper Target -> General Tab -> Bundle Identifier, added 'XYZ' prefix to it.

On running the app in console it displayed these messages:

```
10/12/14 6:27:42.159 PM xpcd[554]: (null): Code identity[pid: 11875::Devarshi-Kulshreshtha.XPCShootOut (/Users/devarshi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XPCShootOut-aaedwraccpinnndivoaqkujcmhmj/Build/Products/Debug/XPCShootOut.app)] is not in ACL for container: ~/Library/Containers/Devarshi-Kulshreshtha.XPCShootOut/Data -- allowing access.

10/12/14 6:27:43.712 PM appleeventsd[63]: <rdar://problem/11489077> A sandboxed application with pid 11875, "XPCShootOut" checked in with appleeventsd, but its code signature could not be validated ( either because it was corrupt, or could not be read by appleeventsd ) and so it cannot receive AppleEvents targeted by name, bundle id, or signature. Error=ERROR: #100013  { "NSDescription"="SecCodeCopySigningInformation() returned 100013, -." }  (handleMessage()/appleEventsD.cp #2072) client-reqs-q
```

Neither app performed its intended function nor it displayed the log message added in `listener:shouldAcceptNewConnection:` delegate.

I am clueless. Kindly suggest if I am missing any thing? Is it possible to get XPC service sample app working without a registered mac developer account?

Comment: It is bizarre but for me it suddenly worked when I changed the Bundle Identifier from 'XYZ' to com.<COMPANY>.<HelperName>

Comment: that is really bizarre :-| but I will give it a try, thanks buddy :) If it worked you can post it as answer, I will mark it as accepted answer once verified :)

Comment: @Anno2001 for some reasons it is still not working :( can  you share the code which worked for you?

Comment: Hi, although long time may have passed since you've published the question, but perhaps you can share a solution if you reached any ? I'm currently struggling a similar scenario. thanks !

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can launch XPC services without having them signed.

Even for testing and debugging the code sign build infrastructure needs to be setup.

I think the Mac developer certificate is free you don't need a paid account for that.